# VBA set cell value after .ClearContents

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Why does the cell value not set in another function when clearing the contents of the range in another function?

I'm trying to set a cell value to "All" after clearing the cells in the range. I've even tried to get a message box to pop up to see if i can somehow check if my check value is correct.

`DelRange` is the range i'm clearing.

`Building` is the cell that i'm checking the value for and if it's blank, it needs to change to "All".

`clearPreviw` is used to clear another sheet, which it's doing.

```
Sub ClearSheet()

Dim Dash As Worksheet
Dim DelRange As Range
Dim Building As Range
Set Dash = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DASH")
Set DelRange = Dash.Range("FilterData")
Set Building = Dash.Range("SelBuild")

  DelRange.ClearContents
  Call clearPreview

 'This part below doesn't work when the Range.ClearContents has been done, but doing it on it's own without clearing the range works fine
  If Building.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Building is empty", vbOKOnly
        Building.Value = "All"
  End If

End Sub
```

I've run this test as a separate process which works, but once again when running it as a call function right after `.ClearContents` seems to stop this.

```
Sub test()

Dim Dash As Worksheet
Dim DelRange As Range
Dim Building As Range
Set Dash = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DASH")
Set DelRange = Dash.Range("FilterData")
Set Building = Dash.Range("SelBuild")

    If Building.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Building is empty", vbOKOnly
        Building.Value = "All"
    End If

End Sub
```

I've been poking at it and searching but i can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: I can't tell from what you posted what the actual problem is. `ClearSheet` doesn't do anything to the `Building` range.

Comment: It is very unclear what your actual question is because you didn't ask one! Make sure you ask something other than “*Can someone help me?*” (see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)) Also unclear "*but doing it with ClearSheet doesn't seem to fire the function.*" (1) which function? (2) where in the code? (3) which is the procedure you initially called? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Rory Thanks for the feedback, `ClearSheet` is being used to clear the range of cells that include the cell from the range `SelBuild`. My problem is that after clearing the range that includes the Cell that i need to change to "All", i cannot apply the value "All" to the cell.

Comment: @Peh, Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure how to ask the question otherwise. Why can't i apply a value to a cell after clearing the contents?

I've tried setting `Building.Value = "All"` with the `Clearsheet` function but it seems to be doing nothing.

Comment: @JakesVanNiekerk You need to be very precise in explaining what you are doing. There is no `Building.Value = "All"` in the procedure `Clearsheet`. Nor did you answer any of my 3 questions. So how can you expect a good answer if you don't provide the information. Help us help you. We need **exactly** the code you are running. And answer the questions as precisely as you can. You can [edit] your question to add something.

Comment: @Peh, Thanks i've edited the question. Let me desensitize the info on the sheet and share the workbook.

I've just thought of something now. I have the sheet checking for changes on that same range and then applying filters according to the cell values in that range. Would i need to stop the sheet change until `.ClearContents` is done and the new value has been applied to the `Building` range?

Comment: @JakesVanNiekerk you can easily test this by debugging the code step-by-step using F8. Go through your code and see what happens in every single step. That's a common way to find bugs in your code and you should be familiar with that when you write own code.

Comment: Is SelBuild a single cell? If not I would advise using a for each cell in range loop to set the values to "All" if they are blank. If it is a single static cell, try referencing the cell directly perhaps

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor doesn't matter if it is a range or a single cell. Even `Range("A1:A5").Value = "All"` would fill in `All` into all 5 cells of that range.

Comment: @Peh True but if any one of those cells contained a value, the IF statement wouldn't trigger, right?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor no the `IF` statement would cause a *run time error 13* if the range is not a single cell: `If Range("A1:A5").Value = "" Then '=> error 13`

Comment: If you are doing this from a Change event, you need to disable events while it's running as it will trigger further change events otherwise.

Comment: @Rory you are 100% correct. After removing the Change event, it worked. If i understand the issue correctly, please correct me if i'm wrong, it seems like as soon as the range is cleared, the Change event triggers and stops the `*.Value` from running.
For now for the purpose of sending in the dashboard to the client for presentation, I've created an "All" button to apply only the value and not run `.ClearContents`. I'll fix it in the week and post the solution.

Comment: To prevent the Change event from running while your code makes changes, use `Application.Enableevents = False` then your code, then `Application.Enableevents = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing:

```
Building.ClearContents;
```

Also I would prefer:

```
If IsEmpty(Building.Value) Then
```

over:

```
If Building.Value = "" Then
```

Comment: Thank Felix, let me have a look

Comment: Make sure your cell or range Set as  'Building' is actually properly named in your sheet  "SelBuild" and you are not manipulating the naming in your code.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa139976(v=office.10).aspx) link gives you a good start on how to set range variables (although I would advice you against the use of `.Select` and `.Activate`).

After that, use [`.ClearContents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-clearcontents-method-excel) or [`.Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-clear-method-excel), depending on your needs.

If you properly cleared the ranges, there is no need to check if they are empty, so this might be a redundant step within your current planning.

Comment: David, I have been truing to actually set the value of `Building` as part of `Worksheet_Change` and found that the cell value wasn't changing, thus the check if the range is empty.
It only doesn't work when `.ClearContents` was run in another function.